# When does a variable need an @ and when does it not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to enhance the default Shared/Error.cshtml that comes with the standard MVC template in VS2013.  The model is `System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo` and I added the following:

```
@foreach (var key in Model.Exception.Data.Keys)
  <li>@key : @Model.Exception.Data[key]</li>
```

It gives an error in the `key` in @Model.Exception.Data[key]: `The name 'key' does not exist in the current context`.

Why and how do I get each value from the dictionary Data?

Comment: Is the code a direct copy? In which case you are missing curly brackets {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    @foreach (var key in Model.Exception.Data.Keys)
    {
      <li>@key : @Model.Exception.Data[key]</li>
    }
```

razor need "{" to know that the code is inside the foreach loop